# Weird characters appear after I use php's mb_substr() on a string

Tags: php, character-encoding, multibyte-functions

I'm developing a web site with PHP (5.3.5, Ubuntu)  and all the content is in Spanish. I would like to cut the text when it doesn't fit the space designated for it. I have the following meta tag in the php file where I want to do this: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />.`

The text comes from a MySQL database where charset is **latin1** and collation **latin1_spanish_ci**. I'm trying to cut the text with the mb_substr() function. But it isn't working correctly. For example, let's say I want to cut *Short Psicodélico* to *Short Psicodéli*, the function would be:

`mb_substr('Short Psicodélico', 0, 15, 'ISO-8859-1');`

But the result is something like this: *Short Psicod&ea*. The e with the diacritic is transformed in *&ea* and I don't know why. I think it has something to do with the character encoding but I don't know exactly how. If I don't use this function the characters appear as they should, instead of *Short Psicod&ea* it shows *Short Psicodélico*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text is encoded in the database as `"Short Psicod&eacute;lico"`. You will need to [scrub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_cleansing) your database to remove the encoding, as well as fix your input routines to make certain that text is not saved to the database encoded.

Comment: Actually in the DB I have 'Short Psicodélico' but I was applying htmlentities() to the string **BEFORE** I cut the string. But I wouldn't have noticed it if you didn't bring up *&eacute;*. Thank you! Now, I cut the string first, then I apply htmlentities() and it works fantastic! =)